# How to check that a class is displayed with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<td class="base-detail-value"><strong>ORDER DATE: </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;19-May-2016 17:52:33
    <span class="tooltip">
        <div class="tt-content">
        May 19, 2016 10:52:33 AM PDT
        </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

I just want to check that td class='base-detail-tooltip' is displayed on the page I'm testing.

I tried doing this, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
logo = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'base-detail-tooltip')
logo.is_displayed()
```

Comment: the example you show doesn't have the 'base-detail-tooltip'??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
logo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.base-detail-tooltip')
```

Note that `.` indicating that we're looking for a class. That's just how CSS works. Before you were looking for a `<base-detail-tooltip>...</base-detail-tooltip>` tag. Since the tag you want is a `td`, you could also use `td.base-detail-tooltip`.

Another note on your code is that the locator `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.base-detail-tooltip')` has to be passed as a tuple, i.e. (note the double parentheses):

```
driver.find_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.base-detail-tooltip'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi simplest way is **please note answer is in java**

```
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".base-detail-tooltip")).size() > 0){
System.out.println("element is present on page")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use try/catch block to check if element exists or not

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        

try:
    webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
except NoSuchElementException:
    return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out,

```
Boolean actual = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(classname)).Displayed
Assert.True(actual, "error message");
```